# What to do when an injected bean stays null?

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-weld

In my application, I have a class which use a reference to a `Utils` class. Wanting to be CDI friendly, I write

```
public abstract class CommonClientBase<InterfaceType> {

    /**
     * Used utility class
     */
    private @Inject Utils utils;
}
```

Where Utils is a simple class with absolutely NO constructor, and NO injected field.

I must add that my project has a META-INF/beans.xml file declared, containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd
          http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans_1_1.xsd">
    <weld:scan>
        <weld:exclude name="org.granite.cdi.**"/>
    </weld:scan>
</beans>
```

So, what can make my `utils` reference to stay `null` after application loading and, more important, how can i solve that null-ness ?

As an aside, i must say this code used to work with Weld `1.0.1-Final`, but now fails with Weld `1.1.4.Final`

**EDIT** Also notice that abstract class is also used through qualified instances of subclasses :

```
@JndiClient
public class ClientEJBInterfaceJndiClient extends CommonClientBase<ClientEJBInterface> implements ClientEJBInterface {
}
```

Which are generated from some server-side code.

Comment: If your Utils class is not in the excluded package, it's possibly a bug...can you try (for the sake of the experiment) make a producer that @Produce an Utils instance.

Comment: @Bozho I already tried, and it changed nothing. For the record, I also tried making my class non abstract, and it also changed nothing.

Comment: Are you using a concrete instance of your abstract class?

Comment: @LightGuard As you can see, i have a concrete subtype : `ClientEJBInterfaceJndiClient`. I use this subtype in my test.

Comment: @LightGuard I asked an associated question on [JBoss user forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/196716)

Comment: Is there anything in jboss log? If your Utils declare a dependency for something that is not in the classpath, it will not get injected.

Comment: @FabricioLemos that Utils class simply isolate some properties file loading, and as a consequence has no dependency over anything else than JDK.